# SQL: loop over every entry in a table and create a new one with rowname, Columname and entry

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table called "tb_Object" that looks like this:

```
ObjektID    Name    ID1    ID2    ID3
----------------------------------------
     1      O1       1     2.30   0.002
     2      O2       2     3.40   0.004
     3      O3       1     2.10   0.200
...
```

I would like to convert it into a table that looks like this:

```
PK_ID     ObjektID    Name       ColName
-----------------------------------------
  1         1         O1    1      ID1
  2         2         O2    2      ID1
  3         3         O3    1      ID1
... 
110         1         O1    2.30   ID2
111         2         O2    3.40   ID2
112         3         O3    2.10   ID2
...
220         1         O1    0.002  ID3
221         2         O2    0.004  ID3
222         3         O3    0.200  ID3
...
```

I know that this is pretty easy in Python. But I have no clue how I could do this in SQL/T-SQL, especially because I can`t use indexing. Does anyone know how to handle this in a smart way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your number of columns is not too high, you could use UNION statement to turn it into the desired format:

```
;with cte as
(select 1 as ObjektID,'O1' as Name,1 as ID1,2.3 as ID2,0.002 as ID3 UNION
select 2 as ObjektID,'O2' as Name,2 as ID1,3.4 as ID2,0.004 as ID3 UNION
select 3 as ObjektID,'O3' as Name,1 as ID1,2.1 as ID2,0.200 as ID3)

select  row_number() over(order by Objektid,Name,ColName) as PK_ID,
        a.*
from
(select ObjektID,Name,'ID1' as ColName,ID1 as Value from cte
UNION
select ObjektID,Name,'ID2' as ColName,ID2 as Value from cte
UNION
select ObjektID,Name,'ID3' as ColName,ID3 as Value from cte) a
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Another way to do this would be using UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT  row_number() over(order by ObjektId,ColumnName) as PK_ID,
        ObjektID, name, ColumnName, Value  
FROM   
   (select ObjektID,Name,ID1,ID2,ID3 from cte) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (Value FOR ColumnName IN   
      (ID1, ID2, ID3)) as unpvt;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'd guess that might not be a very practical solution for more than 100 rows?

Comment: Number of rows might not have too much impact, but the number of columns will. If you are dealing with just 3 columns, this query should work fine

Comment: I added another way to do this using UNPIVOT...check it out

Comment: Oh nice, didn't knew there is a PIVOT and UNPIVOT function in T-SQL! Thanks a lot!